# How CSS inheritance works in non-direct child elements?

Tags: html, css

Hi I’m new in the CSS world i have a doubt about how CSS inheritance works in this example:

HTML:

```
<body>
  <h1>My website</h1>
  <div>
    <p>Hello world</p>
  </div>
  <p>Social</p>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {font-size: 15px;}
```

We can see that in this code we have 2 direct child elements (h1, div, p), so it makes sense to me that the font-size property should be applied to these directly, but how does it work for non-direct child elements? , we know that the p element inside the div will also have the property applied; what i want to know is if this works as a chain? So the body inherits the property to the div element and the div inherits to the p element? Is this how inheritance works for non-direct child elements?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. We normally talk of the child inheriting from the parent, rather than the parent inheriting to the child though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a run down on [CSS Specificity](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp).

The general rule is:

default => element specific => classes => IDs => in-line

and in element specific, the closer the parent to the child the higher the Specificity Value.

In your example body has a style that is overriding the default styles, so all of the children inside the  tags are inheriting it (the body parent is closer than the default html parent) and there isn't a more specific css style to override that.

If you were to add

```
div {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

then your paragraph would inherit the div styles (as it's a closer parent than body), but your heading would retain the body style (it's not a child of a div).

I hope this clarifies.